# Sort a ArrayList of Objects based on parameter with IComparable

Tags: c#, sorting, arraylist, icomparable

I created a small test program to gain some experience with the IComparable interface in C#. I need to use the interface for other stuff in future.

In the program I'd like to sort a ArraList of customers based on the salary. Executing my code I always receive the "**System.InvalidOperationException**" exception.

I already tried different versions of the code and checked a few tutorials, always with the same result.

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;

namespace CsTest
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 101,
                Name = "Ted",
                Salary = 4000
            };

            Customer customer2 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 102,
                Name = "Tod",
                Salary = 7000
            };

            Customer customer3 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 103,
                Name = "Tom",
                Salary = 5500
            };

            ArrayList listCustomers = new ArrayList();
            listCustomers.Add(customer1);
            listCustomers.Add(customer2);
            listCustomers.Add(customer3);

            Console.WriteLine("Customers before sorting");
            foreach (Customer customer in listCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name + " - " + customer.Salary);
            }

            // Sort() method should sort customers by salary
            listCustomers.Sort();

            Console.WriteLine("Customers after sorting");
            foreach (Customer customer in listCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name + " - " + customer.Salary);
            }
        }
    }

public class Customer : IComparable<Customer>
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

        public int CompareTo(Customer obj)
        { 
            return this.Salary.CompareTo(obj.Salary);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you getting this exception and why are you using ArrayList instead of List ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you want to use an `ArrayList` instead of a `List<Customer>`? A typed List is suggested in general, as it will only accept objects of the specified type.

The issue here is that `ArrayList.Sort()` does not use the `IComparable` interface. Check the remarks [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.arraylist.sort?view=netcore-3.1#System_Collections_ArrayList_Sort), where it states that you have to implement the `IComparer` interface and use the `.Sort(comparer)` overload.

This is your one option. The other option (much much easier) is to use a `List<Customer>` and it will use your `IComparable` implementation out of the box. Your choice :)

Comment: Actually I only used ArrayList because it was also used in the tutorials. I tried with List<> and every worked fine. Big Thanks!

Comment: Yeah `ArrayList` is to be avoided nowadays. Its big cousin, `List<T>` does the same things and is much more versatile and safe.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution using original ArrayList

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            Customer customer1 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 101,
                Name = "Ted",
                Salary = 4000
            };

            Customer customer2 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 102,
                Name = "Tod",
                Salary = 7000
            };

            Customer customer3 = new Customer()
            {
                ID = 103,
                Name = "Tom",
                Salary = 5500
            };

            ArrayList listCustomers = new ArrayList();
            listCustomers.Add(customer1);
            listCustomers.Add(customer2);
            listCustomers.Add(customer3);

            Console.WriteLine("Customers before sorting");
            foreach (Customer customer in listCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name + " - " + customer.Salary);
            }

            // Sort() method should sort customers by salary

            Customer sortCustomer = new Customer();
            listCustomers.Sort(sortCustomer);

            Console.WriteLine("Customers after sorting");
            foreach (Customer customer in listCustomers)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(customer.Name + " - " + customer.Salary);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Customer : IComparer 
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }

          int IComparer.Compare( Object x, Object y )  {
          return( (new CaseInsensitiveComparer()).Compare( ((Customer)x).Salary, ((Customer)y).Salary) );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so I need to use Linq for sorting the ArrayList?